# Не рисует диагональную линию в ZedGraph

Tags: c#

Всё остальное программа считает правильно но возникла проблема с выводом графика.
А именно `ZedGRaphControl` не хочет его рисовать

Вот как примерно должно выводится

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот как выводится сейчас

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первое что пришло в голову это неправильный код самого уравнения регрессии(сами числа правильные). Всё таки ZedGraph должен брать данные откуда-то а если источник неверный то и рисование будет неверным.

Элементарная математика как я помню. Мы делим часть без икса на часть с иксом (предварительно перенеся их по разным сторонам)
Или же я забыл школьный курс?И код написано неправильно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public double linregres()//Линейная регрессия
        {
            return 2.8/-0.12;
        }
```

**UPD**

Добился того что линия появилась но она не диагональная
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось просто.
Нужно оригинал формулы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подставить в часть кода где происходит построение по точкам(ZedGraph)

```
 for (int i = 0; i < kkol; i++)
            {
                for (int xx = 0; xx < xmax; xx += 1)
                {
                    list1.Add(X[i], calcsysteqa() * X[i] + calcsysteqb());
               }
            }
```

где `0.1196 - это calcsysteqa()`, `2.7951 - это calcsysteqb()`, а `x - это массив выборки X[i]`-который указывается в задаче.
Собственно и его нужно задавать в качестве координаты по оси x.

Также X[i] нужно подставлять в формулу уравнения линейной регрессии.Так как цикл выше перебирает значения массива и подставляет их в уравнение,где происходит и вычисление координаты для диагональной линии путём умножения `X[i]` на `calcsysteqa()` и прибавлением на `calcsysteqb()`.

Никакой формулы отдельной `public double linregres()` не требуется

А вот и нужный график

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]